# Pull specific rows of data when they meet a conditional statement

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to use xlrd to pull only certain rows of information from a large spreadsheet (over and over again for 100+ other spreadsheets). Specifically, I need a script that can comb the rows of a spreadsheet and pull out all the rows that start with a particular string (`bike`, for example). That is, once the script finds the row that starts with `bike`, I need to it print out `bike` and the value in the cell next to it (which also happens to be the entire row). This is what I have so far, but I keep getting a syntax error after `bike`:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1') 


for row in range(worksheet.nrows):
    if worksheet.row_values(row) == 'bike'
        print worksheet.row_values(row)
    else:
        print 'Code not found'
```

Comment: You need a `:` at the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: You probably also want to do `if worksheet.row_values(row)[0] == 'bike':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error is a missing colon:

```
if worksheet.row_values(row) == 'bike':
```

But I think this statement will always return false because `row_values` returns a slice, not a string literal.  You can probably check the first cell like:

```
if worksheet.row_values(row)[0] == 'bike':
```